# Rspec: testing Mac OS app integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a Rails app that interacts with some Mac software and I need to write some tests for it. How on earth do I do that? Where do I even start?

The Rails app connects to the Mac app through AppleScript and Terminal. Any ideas?

**Update**

Found this gem to help with Shell expectations. Is that as good as I'm gonna get?

https://github.com/matthijsgroen/rspec-shell-expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing external dependencies can certainly be a challenge.

Remember that tests you write should test the behavior of the Rails app, not the external dependency. You should have integration tests to verify that the code actually works with the application, but they should be "smoke tests", not a full suite to test every feature.

Write unit tests to verify the behavior of the code that relies on the dependency, and mock out the interactions. Typically with command line apps that means:

- the app wrote to STDOUT
- the app wrote to STDERR
- the app read from STDIN
- the app exited with a particular status code

The gem you mentioned is a good start, but you may find it worthwhile to look at rolling your own helper code using [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) from the Ruby standard library, which can be useful for all the items in the list above.

Use a tag on the specs that need to use the Mac application to make it easier to filter out those specs as necessary.

You may already be familiar with [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) for mocking out HTTP interactions; its "playback" feature is a good source of inspiration.

Comment: Also, the AppleScript I mentioned earlier *is* part of the Rails app. If that makes a difference to recommendations.

Comment: If you are including AppleScript in the app code then yes, it makes a difference. I'd make sure there is a unit test to exercise that code. I assume you are deploying to a server that runs AppleScript? That's a bit unusual.

Comment: Something like that, yeah: the AppleScript is part of the Rails app and manages the integration between Mac software and Rails. Unusual is right, ha, which is why I need some guidance. :)